# Please add a "When should I delete answers?" section to the 20k privileges description page

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers, trusted-user

The [privileges description for 10k rep](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) has a pretty in-depth explanation of how deleting posts works, and it elaborates on specifically *when* you should consider voting to delete a question under the subsection titled "When should I delete questions?". I find this very helpful, not only for my own guidance but also because I can point other people to it if necessary.

Now that the new `/review` pages contain both "Delete" and "Recommend Deletion" buttons for low quality posts (determined by your rep as I understand), I think it would be beneficial to have a similar sub-section in the 20k privileges paged entitled "When should I delete **answers**?" [The current version](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user) points out that you gain this power upon hitting 20k rep, but it completely glosses over it and provides no direction on how to effectively (and responsibly) use this power.

Although presumably we're trusting the "trusted users" to make good judgments here, I think that at least having some kind of basic guidelines codified would be very beneficial.

Comment: Technically, anyone can edit those. They just have to be pushed out across the network by a developer, which hasn't happened for a while, it seems.

Comment: One can always use the same rules as for deleting questions. Deleting a question also deletes all its answers, so by applying the same policy we can only err on the side of caution.

Comment: Deleting answers by 20ks rarely happens. On the other hand 20ks deleting questions is a problem IMO.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Part of what motivated this is that I would not be surprised if it happened more frequently with the new beta review system as the delete button feels somewhat more prominent now.

Comment: @animuson: Really? How do you edit the privileges pages? I didn't know that was possible. **Edit**: Oh, I think I don't have enough rep on MSO to see the link and such. In any case, it's not something I can currently do myself, it seems.

Comment: There's more than enough "me too" and "thanks" NAA style answers for 20K users to use all their delete votes everyday.